Next.js with Contentful CMS, acces denied on a client component
Im working on my first Next.js app. Im using Contentful also for the first time (first time with a CMS) So far I really enjoy Next and everything is smooth sailing. But now I ran into some problem when I have a component that is supposed to first take the name of whatever the user have clicked on, and then make use a query to get all the stuff that is in the reference field of whatever the user have clicked on.
The query works fine in the Graphql playground on Contentful, but when Im using it in the app I get 401 and it says my accecss token is invalid.
This is not true ofcourse since Im using the same access token all over the application and it works fine on all other places besides this one component. And this is the only one that Im using the 'use client' since I needed to have useState. So my guess is that thats the problem. But I dont know how to work around it.
So this is the query:
const GET_PARTNERS_BY_CATEGORY = gql`
query ($category: String!) {
  partnerKategorierCollection(where: { kategorinamn: $category }) {
    items {
      partnersCollection {
        items {
          ... on Partners {
            title
            slug
            huvudpartner
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`

Im using fragments to be able to acces the names of the referencefields and as i said it works fine in the playground.
And then I have a clickhandler to make the fetch:
const Grid = ({ gridItems, children, className, ...props }) => {
  const [view, setView] = useState('categories');
  const [partners, setPartners] = useState([]);

  const handleCategoryClick = async (categoryName) => {
    console.log('Clicked category:', categoryName);
    try {
      const { data } = await apolloClient.query(
        {
          query: GET_PARTNERS_BY_CATEGORY,
          variables: { 
            category: categoryName, 
          }
        }
      )

      const fetchedPartners = data.partnerKategorierCollection.items[0]?.partnersCollection.items ?? [];
      setPartners(fetchedPartners);
      setView('partners');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching partners:', error);
    }
  };

so the idea is that if the user clicks a category I want to get all the partners that are a part of that category, and they are stored as a reference in the category contentmodel.
but when I click on a category I get 401 and this in the response tab:
 {
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Authentication failed. The access token you provided is invalid",
            "extensions": {
                "contentful": {
                    "code": "ACCESS_TOKEN_INVALID",
                    "requestId": "a requestID =)"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}


So to summarize:

I know the accesstoken is NOT invalid since it works fine on all other places on the app.
I would think its becouse of the component being a client component? since that is the only real difference from all the other fetches and querys.


Since the request is going from the client, check the network tab to make sure that the access token is in fact being passed. If you're using an environment variable for the access token, it should have the prefix NEXT_PUBLIC for it to be accessible from the client. On a side note however, if you can, avoid the use of secrets in client requests, anyone can open the network tab and inspect the access token used. Chances are, what you're trying to achieve can easily be done with a server action.

u saved my life now i know the logic @moonstar-x but you must make a different value for env i think for security because it will consume as public thats my your value will exposed . in my case i use it as a token . we must create a new logic to handle more secure or just make it all on server side .

I don't think I understood your point correctly. Just as a recap, whenever you're using secret values, such as tokens and api keys, NEVER share them to a client if they're supposed to remain private. This means that client-side React code should never make API requests that require a service token. Your requests should originate from a server context, whether that's a Next.js server action, server component, or your own API.
